# Is there a 'general logical error exception'?

Tags: java, exception

Often, if an exception is going to be thrown, then there is something totally broken with your code, and there's not much you can do about it.

For example, if I'm setting up my dataSource:

```
    try {
        Class.forName("org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver");        
    this.jdbcTemplate  = new JdbcTemplate(this.dataSource);
```

If this exception is thrown, clearly I need to sort out my code.

Obviously I shouldn't just print this stack trace, probably the better thing to do, is pop the exception up, alert the user that something has gone wrong, notify the administrators, and log the error.

My question is - what should I be doing here? Do I just throw the ClassNotFoundException? Or can I wrap it in a more generic 'This exception is fatal' exception?

Comment: You can always create your won exception by extending an existing one.

Comment: @PM77-1 Yeah - but I imagine if this was a good idea, it would have already been done, and would be well implmented.

Comment: http://www.journaldev.com/1696/java-exception-handling-tutorial-with-examples-and-best-practices#best-practices

Comment: As a matter of fact you don't need that `Class.forName()` line at all, so the whole question is moot. It hasn't been necessary since JDBC 4 in 2007. As long as the Neo4J driver is JDBC 4-compliant, of course, but it almost certainly is.

Comment: I assume no one felt the need to package something so trivial, @dwjohnston. There's virtually  nothing to implement, "well" or otherwise.  MyException extends RuntimeException... done.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an `assert` statement. The entire purpose of an `assert` statement is to find and flag bugs.

In your particular case, I suppose you could do something like this:

```
try {
    Class.forName("org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
    assert (false) : "Class org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver doesn't seem to exist. "
                   + "Please find the address of the developer of this program, "
                   + "knock on his door, and demand your money back.";
}
```

(totally a joke)

Comment: The reality is - because `Class.forName` throws and exception, I need to handle it somehow.

Comment: I think you still need to couple it with logging as much pertinent information as possible.

Comment: @PM77-1 Yeah, this was just a minimal example.